# Bigcommerce - Custom Product templates in Stencil

Tags: templates, product, bigcommerce

I've noticed that there isn't a Template dropdown for each Product in Stencil's backoffice.

Previously we could select different templates per Product. ( ex: "_customProductTemplate.html"

Does anyone know/use a method to create dynamic, product based, template selections?

Thanks,

- Aaron

Answer (score 2):

~This is not something currently available in Stencil. It is slated on the roadmap.~

You can now make these changes. You can see more details for the step by step instructions listed here: https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/authoring-custom-templates

Answer (score 2):

To create custom templates for product you need to place the file(e.g _customProductTemplate.html) in template/pages/custom/product directory.

To test it locally, you need to assign the custom template to the url in .stencil file. For example,

```
"customLayouts": {
  "products": {"_customProductTemplate.html":"/{custom-product-url}/"},
  "pages": {},
  "brands": {},
  "categories": {}
}
```

Currently, this feature is in beta and so you cannot assign the custom template to the desired product in bigcommerce server. However you can do so by requesting bigcommerce customer service to enable this feature for your site and by accepting their condition for beta not supporting many features.